# Creating a Decision Tree Chart

Tags: javascript, python, graph, tree, plot

I am Using R to create a decision tree but need a web base control that will allow be to plot the tree.  I have all of the node info but need to plot.  Is there any open source tool that will allow me to do this?  I prefer python or a javascript control.

Thanks

Comment: I need to create a chart.  I have the nodes in parent child format.  The charts from R do not suffice.   I need something more pretty.

Answer (score 0):

Plot your decision tree to a PNG or JPG, save it to a file, serve it via your Webserver.

If I remember correctly the code would be something like this:

```
jpeg('rplot.jpg')
plot(x,y)
dev.off()
```

Comment: I need to create a chart. I have the nodes in parent child format. The charts from R do not suffice. I need something more pretty.

Answer (score 0):

While I was searching for ways to plot graphs with JS, I came across [D3](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/). I haven't used it yet, but it looked promising.

Comment: Hi...checked in out...it looks great.  I a playing with it now.

Answer (score 0):

I am using JavaScript [InfoVis toolkit](http://thejit.org/demos/) that offers support for variety of tree visualizations and beyond. Of course, it means that you'll need a browser to run this but it works pretty well.

As for Python, use it to map your tree structure to InfoVis json format for trees.